# How to dynamically change values of a flag based on date range in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, flags, date-range

I'm looking for an optimal solution to below problem. Please find attached a rough schema of my problem. There's a student '2' and three course IDs; A,B and D.
My class flag denotes 'T' for classes the student should attend( though he can attend non Mandatory courses as well for eg., course with ID 'B'). I want to create a new flag based on this existing class flag.

If my time period is between 1-12 Jan, then I should get the output marked in blue. However, if my time period is 12-20Jan, then the new flag column should have all zeroes as no mandatory course was attended during that time period. Can someone please let me know how to change the values of a flag dynamically with change in my time period? [The new column needed is marked in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhPV5.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried already to solve this problem? It would be helpful if you posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve above using a calculated field [Refer this Tableau Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DRzb.png).

Calculated field code:

`// first hardcode ID based on mandatory or optional field
if ([ID]='A' or [ID]='B') AND INT(DAY([Dt]))<=12 
    then  '1'
    ELSE '0'
END`

Above code check each student's record ID and date field return results as in one calculated field.